# Drupal 7 Theming a view

Tags: drupal, view, styles, themes

I've created a views called event which lists all 'event' content type pages, however I want to style the list by adding a "read more" button as well as other styles. I have created a blank template called views-view--event.tpl.php and I can see now that this is used because the view no longer lists the pages, instead it is blank (as expected). However, how do I now add the pages back in? I.e what php variables etc can I access from here? I've tried to echo a simple $title but this doesn't work. Is there a global variable that I can access? If so, what is it? I simply want to replicate what the view was doing before I created the template but with the ability to style it how I wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your view display and look at the bottom of the "advanced" column. You'll see something like "Theme : Information". Try to locate your template name and click on it to get it's base code.

Comment: I've done what you said for another view I have called 'upcoming_event' to see what that uses and this is what I get:


    Display output: views-view.tpl.php, views-view--upcoming-events.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--page.tpl.php, views-view--upcoming-events--page.tpl.php

Comment: Style output: views-view-unformatted.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--upcoming-events.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--page.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--upcoming-events--page.tpl.php
    Row style output: .tpl.php, --upcoming-events.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --page.tpl.php, --upcoming-events--page.tpl.php

Comment: views-view.tpl.php and views-view-unformatted.tpl.php are in bold, but if I create a template called views-view--upcoming_event.tpl.php and copy and paste the code from views-view.tpl.php nothing appears?!

Comment: If you click on `Display Output`, you will get the base code for views-view-[yourview].tpl.php. Simply paste it in your `views-view--event.tpl.php` template.

Comment: Sorry, for you new view, paste it in `views-view--upcoming-events.tpl.php`

Comment: Got it now, thanks. However, the view lists all pages with a 'read more' link to each page, where is the 'read more' and how can I style it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand fully. Mind sending me a link to your site? If you want to add a link to all page displays, use `views-view--upcoming-events--page.tpl.php`. To add a link on each node outputted by the view, I would change the display for fields instead of content. Then field templates will appear in `Theme : Information`